# How do I create a read-only access for wiki server?

Tags: osx-server, permission, server.app

I would like to create a new user account for the wiki server but with read only access to the content.

The admin guide says that it can be done but it doesn't say how! Do you happen to know?

Answer (score 1):

it's way simpler that it seemed in the docs.
You just login as an admin account.
Click on the gear icon on the top right
then permissions.
add the user that you would like to set as read only
then from the dropbox on the right select the permission for that user.